# Changing CSS in Twenty Eleven to change font size of body text

Tags: css

How do I alter the CSS of Twenty Eleven so that all the body text in posts and on pages is bigger?

And is the change I make for this in the files on my server, or through the browser in the Admin login of my WordPress account?

(If there's a better way to alter the text size than altering the CSS, then what is that?)

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Yep, this is purely CSS tweak.

Since Twenty Eleven is hosted in official repository and is maintained. Its updates will overwrite any changes you make to it.

You should look into creating [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) for your modifications.

Answer (score 1):

for a list of possible styles to change any font sizes, see style.css of Twenty Eleven, from line 2358:

```
@media (max-width: 650px) {
    /* @media (max-width: 650px) Reduce font-sizes for better readability on smaller devices */
```

changing this one might be sufficient to change size of general body texts:

```
body, input, textarea {
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

ideally, you make these changes to style.css of a [child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), possibly using the ***appearance -> editor***.