# Modify Twentyeleven child theme CSS - How to change body font size?

Tags: child-theme, css, theme-twenty-eleven

I've created a twentyeleven-child theme and activated it.

I'm trying to increase the size of the body font on all pages.

Do I do this in style.css of the twentyeleven-child theme?

I can't find the right font in this file to change.

In attempt to find it, I've searched all 10px, 11px, 12px, 13px, 14px, 15px, and 16px and changed them all to 20px, but the font size of the body text on my site is not increasing.

I know that changes that I'm making to style.css are working, because other things are changing (for example, the menu font size).

Comment: duplicate of http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25232/changing-css-in-twenty-eleven-to-change-font-size-of-body-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body font size in TwentyEleven is listed on line 316 in style.css

```
body, input, textarea {
    color: #373737;
    font: 15px "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 1.625;
}
```

Copy it over to your child theme style sheet and change the 15px to 20px.

If you have already done this and it's not working make sure your child theme style.css has the correct headers:

```
/*
Theme Name: Twenty Eleven Child
Description: Child theme for the Twenty Eleven theme 
Author: Your name here
Template: twentyeleven
*/

@import url("../twentyeleven/style.css");

/* Add your over ride rules below this line */
```

If you need to debug your stylesheet and see which rules are being used by the browser you can use the [webkit inspector included with Chrome](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/) or the [Firebug Firefox plugin](http://getfirebug.com/).

To use the Chrome inspector highlight a section to inspect then right click and choose inspect element.

You can also make on the fly css changes to see what they will look like. (Changes won't be saved when the page is refreshed).

#### See Screenshot Below:

[image]